# Post a form before all tests chai mocha

Tags: node.js, tdd, mocha.js, chai

If I need to submit a login form before all tests, how can I do this with chai and mocha;

I've looked at the beforeEach functions but cant seem to make it work

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var app = require('../app');
var should = chai.should();
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiHttp);

var username = 't@t.com';
var password = 'test';

before(function() {

it('should login with details to login form / POST', function(done) {
    var request = chai.request(app);
    request
        .post('/session/new')
        .field('email', username)
        .field('password', password)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            res.should.have.status(200);
            res.should.be.html;
            done();
        });
});
describe('Vouchers', function() {
    it('should list ALL vouchers on / GET', function(done) {
        var request = chai.request(app);
        request
            .get('/vouchers')
            .end(function(err, res) {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.text.should.match(/Welcome to the Voucher Homepage/);
                res.should.be.html;
                done();
            });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Post some of your code

Comment: @jrbedard done.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put `it` inside a `before` hook. I've tried it to see what would happen and got various results. The behavior you get by doing that is just undefined.

Looking at your code, it looks like you want the code in the first `it` to initialize state and then have the stuff in `describe` run afterwards. To do so, just unwrap the code you've put in your first `it` and make it the body of your `before` hook. And since `chai-http` produces promises, you should be able to just return the request you produce. So this should work:

```
before(function() {
    var request = chai.request(app);
    return request
        .post('/session/new')
        .field('email', username)
        .field('password', password)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            res.should.have.status(200);
            res.should.be.html;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Luois already said, you cannot put it inside a before hook. An the Before, should go inside the describre.

```
describe('Vouchers', function () {
    before(function () {
        var request = chai.request(app);
        return request
            .post('/session/new')
            .field('email', username)
            .field('password', password)
            .end(function (err, res) {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.should.be.html;
            });
    });

    it('should list ALL vouchers on / GET', function (done) {
        var request = chai.request(app);
        request
            .get('/vouchers')
            .end(function (err, res) {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.text.should.match(/Welcome to the Voucher Homepage/);
                res.should.be.html;
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: There's nothing in the OP's question that indicates that the `before` hook needs to be put inside the `describe` block. If it is left top level, it will be run before any test in the suite.

Comment: True, maybe this is only a best practices scenario, but mocha docs says is the "right" way. Because the tests can appear before, after or interspersed with the hooks.  https://mochajs.org/#hooks It is just to keep order.

Comment: The documentation you point to describes it as *one* way, not 'the "right" way'. If you scroll down you'll set a section titled "Root-Level Hooks" that describes how hooks outside any `describe` block are useful.